# Disable JavaScript in Webbrowser Control in AutoHotkey

Tags: dom, webbrowser-control, autohotkey

I thought even after rendering the page, removing script tags and the relevant attributes in tags would work but didn't.

The following code removes the script tag and the onclick attribute but it does not have any effect.

Any idea?

I'd like to avoid:

- editing the registroy since it requires admin rights.
- fetching web contents separately and using doc.write() since it make the code complex.

Files:

- javascript.html
- test.ahk

**javascript.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script> function displayDate() { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date(); }</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo" onclick="displayDate()">This is a paragraph. Click here.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.ahk**

```
    Gui, Add, ActiveX, vWB w400 h300, Shell.Explorer  
    Gui, Show, w420 h320
    WB.Navigate("file:///" A_ScriptDir "/javascript.html")
    Loop
       Sleep 10
    Until (WB.readyState=4 && WB.document.readyState="complete" && !WB.busy)        

    doc := WB.document
    nodeScript := doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
    nodeScript.parentNode.removeChild(nodeScript)
    nodeP := doc.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]
    nodeP.removeAttribute("onclick") 

    msgbox % doc.documentElement.outerHTML
    Return
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to force scripting enabled/disabled for a given WebBrowser control by implementing three specific COM interfaces (`IOleClientSite`, `IServiceProvider` and `IInternetSecurityManager`) and calling the SetClientSite method of the control's IOleObject interface.

Ultimately, you need to implement the `IInternetSecurityManager::ProcessUrlAction` method. When the WebBrowser calls it with the `dwAction` parameter set to `URLACTION_SCRIPT_RUN`, you can set `*pPolicy` to `URLPOLICY_DISALLOW` to prevent scripting or `URLPOLICY_ALLOW` to enable scripting, and return `S_OK` (zero) to enforce the policy.

The necessary code is shown below, and can be implemented by simply calling `SetWBClientSite()` after creating the control but before navigating. The global variable `WB` must contain a reference to the WebBrowser control.

```
/*  Complex workaround to override "Active scripting" setting
 *  and ensure scripts can't run within the WebBrowser control.
 */

global WBClientSite

SetWBClientSite()
{
    interfaces := {
    (Join,
        IOleClientSite: [0,3,1,0,1,0]
        IServiceProvider: [3]
        IInternetSecurityManager: [1,1,3,4,8,7,3,3]
    )}
    unkQI      := RegisterCallback("WBClientSite_QI", "Fast")
    unkAddRef  := RegisterCallback("WBClientSite_AddRef", "Fast")
    unkRelease := RegisterCallback("WBClientSite_Release", "Fast")
    WBClientSite := {_buffers: bufs := {}}, bufn := 0, 
    for name, prms in interfaces
    {
        bufn += 1
        bufs.SetCapacity(bufn, (4 + prms.MaxIndex()) * A_PtrSize)
        buf := bufs.GetAddress(bufn)
        NumPut(unkQI,       buf + 1*A_PtrSize)
        NumPut(unkAddRef,   buf + 2*A_PtrSize)
        NumPut(unkRelease,  buf + 3*A_PtrSize)
        for i, prmc in prms
            NumPut(RegisterCallback("WBClientSite_" name, "Fast", prmc+1, i), buf + (3+i)*A_PtrSize)
        NumPut(buf + A_PtrSize, buf + 0)
        WBClientSite[name] := buf
    }
    global wb
    if pOleObject := ComObjQuery(wb, "{00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
    {   ; IOleObject::SetClientSite
        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(pOleObject+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "ptr"
            , pOleObject, "ptr", WBClientSite.IOleClientSite, "uint")
        ObjRelease(pOleObject)
    }
}

WBClientSite_QI(p, piid, ppvObject)
{
    static IID_IUnknown := "{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    static IID_IOleClientSite := "{00000118-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    static IID_IServiceProvider := "{6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}"
    iid := _String4GUID(piid)
    if (iid = IID_IOleClientSite || iid = IID_IUnknown)
    {
        NumPut(WBClientSite.IOleClientSite, ppvObject+0)
        return 0 ; S_OK
    }
    if (iid = IID_IServiceProvider)
    {
        NumPut(WBClientSite.IServiceProvider, ppvObject+0)
        return 0 ; S_OK
    }
    NumPut(0, ppvObject+0)
    return 0x80004002 ; E_NOINTERFACE
}

WBClientSite_AddRef(p)
{
    return 1
}

WBClientSite_Release(p)
{
    return 1
}

WBClientSite_IOleClientSite(p, p1="", p2="", p3="")
{
    if (A_EventInfo = 3) ; GetContainer
    {
        NumPut(0, p1+0) ; *ppContainer := NULL
        return 0x80004002 ; E_NOINTERFACE
    }
    return 0x80004001 ; E_NOTIMPL
}

WBClientSite_IServiceProvider(p, pguidService, piid, ppvObject)
{
    static IID_IUnknown := "{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    static IID_IInternetSecurityManager := "{79eac9ee-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b}"
    if (_String4GUID(pguidService) = IID_IInternetSecurityManager)
    {
        iid := _String4GUID(piid)
        if (iid = IID_IInternetSecurityManager || iid = IID_IUnknown)
        {
            NumPut(WBClientSite.IInternetSecurityManager, ppvObject+0)
            return 0 ; S_OK
        }
        NumPut(0, ppvObject+0)
        return 0x80004002 ; E_NOINTERFACE
    }
    NumPut(0, ppvObject+0)
    return 0x80004001 ; E_NOTIMPL
}

WBClientSite_IInternetSecurityManager(p, p1="", p2="", p3="", p4="", p5="", p6="", p7="", p8="")
{
    if (A_EventInfo = 5) ; ProcessUrlAction
    {
        if (p2 = 0x1400) ; dwAction = URLACTION_SCRIPT_RUN
        {
            NumPut((URLPOLICY_DISALLOW := 3), p3+0)  ; *pPolicy := URLPOLICY_DISALLOW
            return 0 ; S_OK
        }
    }
    return 0x800C0011 ; INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
}

_String4GUID(pGUID)
{
    VarSetCapacity(String,38*2)
    DllCall("ole32\StringFromGUID2", "ptr", pGUID, "str", String, "int", 39)
    Return  String
}
```

The current AutoHotkey installer contains code identical to this, with the exception that it sets `URLPOLICY_ALLOW` (0) rather than `URLPOLICY_DISALLOW` (3). This was necessary to allow the installer to work on systems which have scripting disabled.

As you can see, implementing COM interfaces directly in an AutoHotkey script is no simple matter. It is a little easier in plain C (see [COM in plain C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C)), and much easier in C++.